# How can I map between tables using fields that aren't primary keys?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have two tables defined as such:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [SomeTable] (
[PrincipalID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[AnotherUniqueField] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Data] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_SomeTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PrincipalID] ASC))

CREATE TABLE [OtherTable] (
[OtherID] [int] NOT NULL,
[UniqueIfNotNullField] [varchar](20) NULL,
[OtherData] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_OtherTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OtherID] ASC))
```

These two tables record information on the same conceptual objects and I would like to be able to create a relationship between them in the EF entities I have for them, using `SomeTable.AnotherUniqueField` and `OtherTable.UniqueIfNotNullField` as the "keys."

`SomeTable.AnotherUniqueField` has a unique index but, obviously, is not the PK.  `OtherTable.UniqueIfNotNullField` is, as indicated, unique when the value is not null.  (This constraint isn't enforced in the database, but the source for the table's data is guarded to guarantee uniqueness when there is a value.)

Here's are the POCO entities:

```cs
public class SomeTable
{
    public int PrincipalID { get; set; }
    public int SameField { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public OtherTable Other { get; set; }
}

public class OtherTable
{
    public int OtherID { get; set; }
    public string SameField { get; set; }
    public string OtherData { get; set; }
}
```

And my `EntityTypeConfiguration` definitions for the same:

```cs
public class SomeTableMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<SomeTable>
{
    public SomeTableMap()
    {
        ToTable("SomeTable");
        HasKey(t => t.PrincipalID);
        Property(t => t.Data)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(t => t.SameField)
            .HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(t => t.PrincipalID).HasColumnName("PrincipalID");
        Property(t => t.SameField).HasColumnName("AnotherUniqueField");
        Property(t => t.Data).HasColumnName("Data");
    }
}

public class OtherTableMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<OtherTable>
{
    public OtherTableMap()
    {
        ToTable("OtherTable");
        HasKey(t => t.OtherID);
        Property(t => t.OtherData)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(t => t.SameField)
            .HasMaxLength(20);
        Property(t => t.OtherID).HasColumnName("OtherID");
        Property(t => t.SameField).HasColumnName("UniqueIfNotNullField");
        Property(t => t.OtherData).HasColumnName("OtherData");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to map this way?  I have tried the following in the constructor for SomeTableMap, but it doesn't work.  I'm at the end of my understanding of custom mappings.

```cs
HasOptional<OtherTable>(x => x.Other)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal()
    .Map(
        map =>
            {
                map.MapKey("UniqueIfNotNullField");
                map.MapKey("AnotherUniqueField");
            });
```

Is this just not a mappable join?  I have another option since `OtherTable` isn't really an editable entity; I can make a view which will include the associated value of SomeTable.PrincipalID, but I'd like to see if this will work first.

**EDIT:** I also tried this:

```cs
HasOptional(x => x.Other)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal()
    .Map(map => map.MapKey("UniqueIfNotNullField"));
```

but I get the error: "`Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'UniqueIfNotNullField' was already defined.`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity framework do not support this relation. The core problem is missing support for Unique constraint in EF. So the key in principal entity always have to be a primary key and if you want to build one-to-one relation the foreign key in dependent entity must be also primary key.

Comment: I feared as much.  Thank you, @Ladislav Mrnka.